# How can you change the shelf icon of a pinned website on ChromeOS?

Tags: google-chrome, chromebook, google-chrome-os

Chrome uses the website's favicon as the shelf icon automatically. Can this be altered?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible, as bookmarks use the icon provided in the webpage contents (I use a chromebook)

Answer (score 0):

There's a solution that worked for me, using Applicationize.me:
https://applicationize.me/now

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.